# TSQL grouping with count

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, counter

My Employee have a Name, an Outlet he must score and he must give a score for the Outlet.
Each Employee can have many Outlets but only 1 Outlet need to be scored at least if that Outlet belongs to that Employee.

So I might have a records like this.

```
Mike -----Outlet1---- 20
Mike----- Outlet2----  0
John----- Outlet3---- 44
Larry---- Outlet4----- 0
```

An employee must at least have 1 score for 1 of the outlets that belong to him.
Thus I do not want to count Mike because he rated an Outlet, I just want to return the value 1 as my result set because Larry did not rate any Outlets.

Table will be: `Select Name, Outlet, Score from TableName`

Comment: What's the "belong to" relationship? or do you mean all names who have a *sum* of scores == 0 ?

Comment: All Mike must have a sum of 0. Meaning single employee must have a sum of 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a count of the names who did not score an outlet.

```
select
  Count(*) as Count
from
(
  select
    Name,
    Sum(Score) as Score
  from
   TableName
  group by
    Name
  having 
    Sum(Score) = 0
) as aa
```